Do you determine a poem's rhyme scheme by stanza or by the text as a whole?
The Tide River
First Stanza
Clear and cool, clear and cool,
By laughing shallow and dreaming pool;
Cool and clear, cool and clear,
By shining shingle and foaming weir;
Under the crag where the ouzel sings,
And the ivied wall where the church-bell rings,
Undefiled, for the undefiled;
Play by me, bathe in me, mother and child.
Second Stanza
Dank and foul, dank and foul,
By the smoky town in its murky cowl;
Foul and dank, foul and dank,
By wharf and sewer and slimy bank;
Darker and darker the farther I go,
Baser and baser the richer I grow;
Who dare sport with the sin-defiled?
Shrink from me, turn from me, mother and child.
Third Stanza
Strong and free, strong and free,
The flood-gates are open, away to the sea.
Free and strong, free and strong,
Cleansing my streams as I hurry along,
To the golden sands, and the leaping bar,
And the taintless tide that awaits me afar.
As I lose myself in the infinite main,
Like a soul that has sinned and is pardoned again,
Undefiled, for the undefiled;
Play by me, bathe in me, mother and child.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about learning the English language. Perhaps it should be asked on Literature Stack Exchange

Hi! Please read about the topics that are covered here. This question is more about how to analyze poetry than how language works. Also, I doubt that there's an "official" answer; literary analysis is something people love to argue over, and is usually a tool to make some point about the work, so as long as your system makes sense to you and others, you could explain the work any way you want.

I assume that your question is: should we call this poem's rhyme scheme
AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMM? Or should we say that the first two stanzas are AABBCCDD and the last stanza is AABBCCDDEE?
If you look at A.E. Housman's poem When I was one-and-twenty, there are lots of websites that say it has a rhyme scheme of ABCBCDAD in the first stanza and ABCBADAD in the second. I couldn't find any websites that gave a rhyme scheme for the poem as a whole (which would be ABCBCDADAEFEAGAG). A few sites said that the rhyme scheme was ABAB, but I suspect that these might have been produced by artificial intelligence, and were confused.
So clearly, the convention is to give the rhyme scheme for each stanza separately. This makes sense — AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLLMM is very difficult to read.
I was reminded by Anna's comment that for sonnets, the convention is to give the rhyme scheme for the poem as a whole. Sonnets are quite short, and the rhyme scheme is not completely regular, so here giving the rhyme scheme for the entire poem makes sense, even if they are divided into stanzas. The rhyme scheme for Shakespearean sonnets is ABABCDCDEFEFGG, for Petrarchian sonnets is one of a handful of possibilities, of which ABBAABBACDECDE is typical, and for French sonnets is again one of a handful of possibilities, of which ABBAABBACCDEDE is typical.

Please refer to this site, https://study.com/learn/lesson/shakespearean-sonnet-ryhme-scheme-form.html  here you can find rhyme scheme for the poem as a whole.

With respect, down-voting for answering a very off-topic question.

Generally speaking, poetry has a recognisable structure. So does all writing. If there was no pattern or structure then you might not even be able to recognise something as poetry.
Having said that, you've probably heard of 'poetic licence'. There is a tremendous amount of linguistic and grammatical flexibility granted in poetry. Often this means other rules of grammar are ignored or just bent a little in order to meet the 'rules' of poetry itself; however, poetry is seen as such an elevated art form that many would say you can bend the rules of poetry itself and still create a valid poem.
While a lot of poems do set rhythm and rhyme schemes that run through the length of the poem, plenty of well-known poems do not For example, "Ode to the West Wind" by Shelley uses a varying rhyme scheme across its five stanzas. The first three stanzas each have a rhyme scheme of ABA BCB CDC DED EE while the final two stanzas maintain a different structure, reflecting the changing subject matter and emotions throughout the poem.

With respect, down-voting for answering a very off-topic question.

I. Rhyme scheme of the poem.

Do you determine a poem's rhyme scheme by stanza or by the text as a whole?

A poem's rhyming scheme is determined by the end letter of each line. Each stanza may have a different rhyme scheme. But the given poem "The Tide river" has the same rhyme scheme throughout the poem.
First Stanza: AABBCCDD.
Second Stanza: EEFFGGHH.
Third Stanza: IIJJKKLLMM.
Every line's final letter is taken into consideration, and its rhyme with the final letter of a nearby line is determined. We utilise the same alphabet if the final word rhymes. We use the next  alphabet if it doesn't rhyme.
II. Rhyming Scheme of the poem.
First line end letter "cool" = A.
Second line end letter   "pool" = A (rhymes with cool).
Third line end letter   "clear" = B
(doesn't rhyme with pool).
Fourth line end letter   "weir" = B (rhymes with clear)
Similarly we can find the rhyme scheme of the whole poem.

With respect, down-voting for answering a very off-topic question.
